# cbegin()/cend() vs constBegin()/constEnd()

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qt5

Qt 5.0 introduced the iterator methods `cbegin()` and `cend()` in the different container classes like [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) or [QMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html).

But there are also `constBegin()` and `constEnd()` methods in those classes.

All those methods are `const` and return an STL-style `const_iterator`.

- Do `cbegin()`/`cend()` have the same functionality than `constBegin()`/`constEnd()` ? For me it seems so, but nothing is stated in the docs of [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html), [QMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html) or the [container classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#stl-style-iterators).
- Is there a scenario where one should use `cbegin()`/`cend()` instead of `constBegin()`/`constEnd()` or vice-versa?

Comment: Check the source, Luke... [QList](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h.html#307), [QMap](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qmap.h.html#521), etc. (TL;DR: they're identical)

Comment: @peppe Good point. But when it is not stated in the docs that they are identical, who guarantees that they will remain identical in future?

Comment: That a behaviour change would break so much code that it's impossible to happen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cbegin()` and `cend()` where introduced for compatibility with Standard Library containers, which all contain such functions since C++11.
Qt just wants to keep it interface similar to the standard library.
`constBegin()` etc. are just older versions (Qt added them before C++11 was released). There is no difference in using them.

I'd use `constBegin()` and `constEnd()` as they are more explicit and 'Qt style', but that just my personal preference. `cbegin()`/`cend()` might be used by some algorithms implemented for standard containers (hence their existence in Qt - they help reuse some code). Use them if you expect that at some point you would like to reuse your code outside Qt.

Comment: Using cbegin et al. makes it easier to substitute standard container types for Qt types in the future.  It also seems to me that Qt has changed its' mind on how to do things.  There used to be a use-only-Qt-functionality-for-everything mindset for while nowadays they say: use standard functionality where that is best and Qt functionality where that is best.

Answer (score 1):

Qt generally often provides different ways of using things, so that programmers can use the style they are used to use.

Simmilar case is with iterators' type. You can use the standard style used in Standard Library or Java style iterators. It's for user's convenience.

The reason for cbegin and constBegin is simillar. Also if documentation does not state difference, then there is no difference.

As you noticed. constBegin is pure QtStyle and cbegin is STL style.